# Filter inside a pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a raw_df like this:

```
   Datum         Kasse   Bon      Articles
0  2021-01-27    101     169      A B C D E
1  2021-01-27    101     176      A C D E F
2  2021-01-27    101     179      B C D
3  2021-01-27    101     195      C D E F
4  2021-01-27    101     203      A E F
```

The column "Articles" represents the bought articles during a specific transaction (they are separated by a blank space).
I use this code to identify the "frequent items":

```
for line in raw_df["Articles"]:
    for item in line.split():
        item_counts[item] += 1

THRESHOLD = 3
frequent_items = { k: v for k, v in item_counts.items() if v > THRESHOLD }
```

In that case, C D E would make it into frequent_items.

In my next step I would like to add a new column to the dataframe similar like "Articles" but only with the elements that are part of frequent_items.
It should look like this:

```
   Datum         Kasse   Bon      Articles   freq_articles
0  2021-01-27    101     169      A B C D E  C D E
1  2021-01-27    101     176      A C D E F  C D E
2  2021-01-27    101     179      B C D      C D
3  2021-01-27    101     195      C D E F    C D E
4  2021-01-27    101     203      A E F      E
```

I tried something like this:

```
raw_df['freq_articles'] = ""
for line in raw_df["Articles"]:
    for item in line.split():
        if item in frequent_items:
            raw_df['freq_articles'] = raw_df['freq_articles'].astype(str) + ' ' + item
```

but it doesn't work. It shows an accumulation of all frequent items in every line.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom lambda function with split values and get only matcing in list, last join back:

```
frequent_items = ['C','D', 'E']

f = lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x.split() if y in frequent_items)
raw_df['freq_articles'] = raw_df['Articles'].apply(f)
print (raw_df)
        Datum  Kasse  Bon   Articles freq_articles
0  2021-01-27    101  169  A B C D E         C D E
1  2021-01-27    101  176  A C D E F         C D E
2  2021-01-27    101  179      B C D           C D
3  2021-01-27    101  195     C D EF           C D
4  2021-01-27    101  203      A E F             E
```

Here lambda function is shorcut for function like:

```
def f(x):
     return ' '.join(y for y in x.split() if y in frequent_items)
raw_df['freq_articles'] = raw_df['Articles'].apply(f)
print (raw_df)
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, this seems to work! Could you please tell me what "lambda" is good for? I understand the join-sequence, but the apply(lambda is new for me.